# Rails putting JSON Data into HTML table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, datatables, html-table

Sorry this could be a real newbie question, but in my Rails 5 app I am trying to parse some JSON and display it into my view as a HTML table.  I tried using https://datatables.net/ but couldn't get it to work, might be worth another post.

So I thought I show what I am doing and ask what is the better way as what I am doing seems really bad.

JSON thats stored as @hosted_zones:

```
{
  "hosted_zones": [{
    "id": "/hostedzone/Z1HSDGASSSME",
    "name": "stagephil.com.",
    "caller_reference": "2016-07-12T15:33:45.277646707+01:00",
    "config": {
      "comment": "Private DNS zone for stage",
      "private_zone": true
    },
    "resource_record_set_count": 10
  }, {
    "id": "/hostedzone/ZJDGASSS0ZN3",
    "name": "stagephil.com.",
    "caller_reference": "2016-07-12T15:33:41.290143511+01:00",
    "config": {
      "comment": "Public DNS zone for stage",
      "private_zone": false
    },
    "resource_record_set_count": 7
  }],
  "is_truncated": false,
  "max_items": 100
}
```

Now my View:

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Caller Reference</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
                <th>private_zone</th>
                <th>Resource Record Set Count</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <% stop = @hosted_zones['hosted_zones'].count %><% start = 0 %>
        <% while start < stop do %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= @hosted_zones['hosted_zones'][start]["id"]%></td>
            <td><%= @hosted_zones['hosted_zones'][start]["name"]%></td>
            <td><%= @hosted_zones['hosted_zones'][start]["caller_reference"]%></td>
            <td><%= @hosted_zones['hosted_zones'][start]["config"]["comment"]%></td>
            <td><%= @hosted_zones['hosted_zones'][start]["config"]["private_zone"]%></td>
            <td><%= @hosted_zones['hosted_zones'][start]["resource_record_set_count"]%></td>
          </tr>
          <% start += 1 %>
        <% end %>
    </table>
```

Surely there is a better way, as this seems really slow and when I get to production which has 400+ records thats never going to load.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `@hosted_zones['hosted_zones'].each do |zone| ... end` is the Ruby way to do a loop where you are primarily concerned with side-effects. `while` and `for` loops are rarely used.

Comment: `when I get to production which has 400+ records thats never going to load` - You should consider pagination